# How can I reformat type of d m Y date using carbon?

Tags: laravel, php-carbon

How can I convert below type of date ? I'm using Carbon, tried with `parse()` or other methods but none of them couldn't help..

```php
$date = "18 Nov, 2017"

$new_date = Carbon::createFromFormat("d m, Y", $date);

dd($new_date->format("Y-m-d"));
```

Above method gives:

> Unexpected data found. The separation symbol could not be found` error

Any advice?

Comment: try "d M, Y". ( M is for 3 letters month format" )

Comment: @barghouthi error lost, but year is incorrect :/

Comment: What is your output for year? I ran this in a unit test and received 2017.

Comment: try YYYY instead of Y

Comment: @barghouthi I removed comma with str replace and not it seems working

Comment: I donno what to day, it should word fine with the comma! last resort is to use `DateTime::createFromFormat('d M, Y', '01 Nov, 2017');`

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need capital M

`$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d M, Y', '18 Nov, 2017');`

- or -

`$carbon_date = Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('d M, Y', '18 Nov, 2017');`

Keep in mind, that your d may or may not need a leading zero too.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```php
$date = "18 Nov, 2017";
$carbonDate = Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('d M, Y', $date);

dd($carbonDate->format('Y-m-d'));
// or 
dd($carbonDate->toDateString());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Carbon;

class DateController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){
        $date = "18 Nov, 2017";
        $carbonDate = Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('d M, Y', $date);
        dd($carbonDate->format("Y-m-d"));
    }
}
```

This gives the correct answer